# Window loosing focus

Tags: c#, forms, setfocus

In my application, when I show a message box and a user clicks any of its button such as OK or CANCEL, my window loses focus and gets minimized.

I had try to use set focus also use win32 API SetForegroundWindow(window hWnd)  to keep the window active. I have noticed if there is another application open behind my window, my application window lost focus after clicking message box button, but in case it is the only visible window on desktop, it works fine. I am working on Windows 7, but I am facing the same problem in Win XP as well.

I am using GradientForm. And to show messagebox, I use MessageBox.Show("Message Text", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon). Nothing different.

Comment: Post your code here. This is not a normal behaviour.

Comment: Are you using winforms -  Mdiparent as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of thing happens when there's no window that's enabled when the message box closes.  Windows is forced to find another window to give the focus to and will pick one from another application.  Also explains why this isn't a problem when there is no other window.

Make sure you don't disable your windows.  In other words, avoid this:

```
   this.Enabled = false;
   MessageBox.Show("oops");
   this.Enabled = true;
```

Setting Enabled back to true like that is too late.

Comment: Fine explanation.But i have checked in                          void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;                        case WM_KILLFOCUS:
                    this.Enabled = true;
                    this.Activate(); 
                    return;
        }But Same problem

Comment: WM_KILLFOCUS can't fix this, it is sent when you *lose* the focus.  In other words, when the message box is displayed.  WM_SETFOCUS can't fix it either, you won't get the focus back.  Just don't mess with the Enabled property.  It isn't necessary, the message box is modal.

Comment: Then what should i need to do?

Comment: *Just don't mess with the Enabled property.  It isn't necessary*

Comment: This helped alot.  However, I have a special situation here - new thread with 'progress window' and I need to disable main window.  How do I go about it without actually setting Enabled=false?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor did you figure this out? Have this issue today and it's losing focus.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by activating window using `setForgroundwindow()` before showing dialog box and every thing is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not showing the message box in the form load event. Because at that time, window is not still initialized.

Instead use Shown event of the form. This will solve this issue